# laravel scheduler in within loop

Tags: cron, laravel-queue, laravel-scheduler

I am confused in laravel queued jobs when I run the code below it processes user_id 1,2,3,4,5 but when it's running after the 1 minute mark it will try to run user_id 1,2,3,4,5 again and not continue with 6,7,8,9,10. I want to run this continuously until it finishes through all the users (meaning I don't know the timing when it will finish going through all the users). How do I go about this?

app/console/kernel

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use App\Exceptions\Handler;
use App\Jobs\UserJob;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {   
        $users = User::where('is_status', 1)->get();
        foreach( $users as $user ){
          $schedule->job( new UserJob($user) )->everyMinute();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

this is my cronjob which runs every minute

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving it a name and add without lapping, perhaps its starting, before its finished. I was struggling with a similar problem.

```
->name('Process Whatever')
->withoutOverlapping()
```